# How to export HTML table with 100K records with number formatting without memory exhaust

Tags: php, mysql, excel, excel-2010

I'm using `PHP` and `MySQL` to fetch the data to `HTML` Table. The data is supposed to download the `HTML` in Excel File. Following code is used:

```
$filename = "individual_list_" . date('Ymdhms') . ".xls";
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    $html='<style>.num {mso-number-format:General;}.text{mso-number-format:"\@";}</style><table border=1>';
    $rowCount=1;
    foreach ($export_data as $key => $row) {
        if(!$header)
        {
            $header_field=array_keys($row);
            $html .='<thead><tr>';
            foreach ($header_field as $k => $value) {      
                $html .='<th class="text">'.$value.'</th>';
            }
            $html .='</tr></head>';
            $header=true;
        }
        $values=array_values($row);
        $rowCount++;
        $html .='<tbody><tr>';
        foreach ($values as $k => $value) {
            if (DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i:s', $value) !== FALSE) {
             $value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));
            }
            $html .='<td class="text">'.$value.'</td>';
        }
        $html .='</tr></tbody>';
    }
    $html .='</table>';
    echo $html;
```

There are around 90K records to export. This code once produced `Allowed Memory Exhausted` Error, So I changed the memory limit. Now the error is resolved but the data is displayed as `HTML Table` instead of download. The code is working good for less recordset. How can the issue be resolved?
The export(download) is done in popup that downloads the Excel file. How can the popup window be closed after download complete?

Comment: "The data is supposed to download the HTML in Excel File." ??

Comment: I meant to say the data displayed in Table supposed to download using the header in PHP

Comment: I've paste answer to my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325128/php-mysql-load-around-100k-records-and-export-them-to-xml/36352017#36352017

Answer (score 0):

Output the html within the loop rather than buffering it until the end. This will reduce the amount of memory required by PHP and may speed up the download process. PHP & your web server will still do some buffering. This is OK but you could override with explicit flush(); commands if the issues persist.

```
$filename = "individual_list_" . date('Ymdhms') . ".xls";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");

echo '<style>.num {mso-number-format:General;}.text{mso-number-format:"\@";}</style><table border=1>';
$rowCount=1;
foreach ($export_data as $key => $row) {
    $html = '';
    if(!$header)
    {
        $header_field=array_keys($row);
        $html .='<thead><tr>';
        foreach ($header_field as $k => $value) {      
            $html .='<th class="text">'.$value.'</th>';
        }
        $html .='</tr></head>';
        $header=true;
    }
    $values=array_values($row);
    $rowCount++;
    $html .='<tbody><tr>';
    foreach ($values as $k => $value) {
        if (DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i:s', $value) !== FALSE) {
         $value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));
        }
        $html .='<td class="text">'.$value.'</td>';
        echo  $html;
    }
    echo '</tr></tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Depending on your MySQL client library, you may also be able to use unbuffered MySQL queries which allow your script to start generating HTML as soon as data is received from MySQL and uses less memory than waiting for the entire result to be loaded into a PHP buffer.

Comment: The above code is still displayed in Table instead of download!

Comment: Are there any errors being logged in the php / server logs?

Comment: Odd. Check the http headers match what you set in your code - you may need to search for instructions related to your browser.  Or if the server is on the Internet, this site will check them for you `http://headers.cloxy.net/`

Comment: I checked and found that even if I passed: `header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");` I'm getting `Content-Type:text/html`. How can I force to use excel as content type