# PHP, MySQL - load around 100k records and export them to xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have MySQL InnoDB table with 1 milion of rows and I selecting 100K rows for export. Table have around 200 columns.

What have I done so far:

1. not select all with *

   SELECT column1, column2, ... FROM my_table WHERE deleted=0 -- load 100k records
2. using XMLWriter php library with flush

   ```
   $writer = new XMLWriter();
   $writer->openMemory();
   $writer->setIndent(true);
   $writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
   $writer->startElement('export');

   $iterator = 0;
   $data = $this->getData();

   foreach($adverts as $advert) {
       $writer->startElement('ad');
       $writer->writeElement('id', $data->id);
       // .. other columns

       $writer->endElement(); // end ad

       if (0 == $iterator % 1000) {
           file_put_contents($this->getFilePath(), $writer->flush(TRUE), FILE_APPEND);
       }

       $iterator++;
   }
   ```

But I still have Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted

Are there any other ways how to optimize that? I think I can maybe load data from database other ways, like load only ids in first round and then select IN (10k_ids), but I don't test this idea yet.

Thank you for your opinions.

---

I have very similar question as in [How to export HTML table with 100K records with number formatting without memory exhaust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168646/how-to-export-html-table-with-100k-records-with-number-formatting-without-memory)

But there is not a way how to achieve low memory consuption.

Comment: People still use XML? ;-)

Comment: Write several files, like 10k each?

Comment: it must be one file. My idea was load 10k with foreach from database so in the variable was saved smaller data

Comment: @ManicDepression how did it work out?

Comment: I load all the data in my question. Now I load only partial data with function getData(). Limit is set to 10 000 records, so I didn't have in variable such a huge data as before around 120 000 records. Also I need ORDER BY to sort items in ascending order, so I can use $id > $lastId from last cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, problem was that I load many data.

I made 3 upgrades:

1. use function to log memory limit

   ```
   /**
    * @param $message
    */
   protected function logMemoryUsage($message)
   {
       Debugger::log($message . ": " . memory_get_usage()/1048576 ." MB");
   }
   ```
2. then I use fopen + fwrite + fclose instead of file_put_contents

   ```
   $file = fopen($this->getFilePath(), 'a+');
   fwrite($file, $writer->flush(TRUE));
   fclose($file);
   ```
3. load data in loop (only 10k records in one time)

   ```
   $this->logMemoryUsage("Memory usage before load");
   $data = $this->getData($lastId);

   do {
       $this->logMemoryUsage("Memory usage");
       $lastId = NULL;

       foreach($data as $item) {
           $writer->startElement('ad');
           $writer->writeElement('id', $item->id);
           ...

           if (0 == $iterator % 5000) {
               fwrite($file, $writer->flush(TRUE));
           }

           $lastId = $item->id;
           $iterator++;
       }

       $data = $this->getData($lastId);

   } while(!empty($data));

   $this->logMemoryUsage("Memory usage after");
   fwrite($file, $writer->flush(TRUE));
   fclose($file);



   public function getData($fromId = NULL, $limit = 10000)
   {
       $data = db::query("SELECT a,b,c FROM my_table WHERE deleted=0 AND id>? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ?", $fromId, $limit)->fetchAll();
   }
   ```

And the output is now:

```
    export start
    Memory usage before load: 3.6202011108398 MB
    Memory usage: 59.487106323242 MB
    Memory usage: 124.53610229492 MB
    Memory usage: 124.89745330811 MB
    Memory usage: 124.43883514404 MB
    Memory usage: 124.20503234863 MB
    Memory usage: 124.2151184082 MB
    Memory usage: 124.46990966797 MB
    Memory usage: 106.50185394287 MB
    Memory usage: 53.009048461914 MB
    export end
```